# Hibernate inheritance, Collections and @OrderedBy superclass attribute generates MySQL syntax Error

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, inheritance

I' using Hibernate 3.6.1 to map three entities

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Entry {
   private Long id; 
   private Date publishedAt; 

   @Id
   public getId() {...}

   ...
}

@Entity
public class Category {
   private Long id; 

   List<Podcast> podcasts;

   @Id
   public getId() {...}

   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "category", cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
   @OrderBy("publishedAt")
   public List<Podcast> getPodcasts() {
      return podcasts;
   }
}
```

and

```
@Entity
public class Podcast extends Entry {

   private Category category; 

   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
   public PodcastsCategory getCategory() {
      return category;
   }
}
```

If i try to fetch a `Category` instance, i get an Exception

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'podcasts0_.Entry.publishedAt' in 'order clause'
```

What causes this exception? Whats wrong with this mapping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's caused by the following bug: [HHH-3577 Wrong SQL in order by clause when using joined subclasses](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-3577).

As a workaround you can remove `@OrderBy` and `fetch = FetchType.EAGER` on `podcasts` and load category using the following query instead of `get()`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c 
FROM Category c LEFT JOIN FETCH c.podcasts p
WHERE c.id = ?
ORDER BY p.publishedAt
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try the annotation [`@MappedSuperClass`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/api/org/hibernate/mapping/MappedSuperclass.html). See section [2.2.4.4. Inherit properties from superclasses](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#d0e1168) of the hibernate documentation.