# Removing both @Entity and @MappedSuperclass in the same class

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0, hibernate-entitymanager

One of the existing classes (class A) has both `@Entity` and `@MappedSuperclass` annotations and the child class (class B extends A) has `@Entity`.

Although this in not right, it is working fine with hibernate-entitymanager 3.3. Both entities have their own table and the table for class B has the same columns as class A plus one additional column that corresponds to its own property.

I'm trying to fix this mistake that was sitting there for years so I can migrate to 3.6 as it does not allow both annotations. (it throws `org.hibernate.AnnotationException: An entity cannot be annotated with both @Entity and @MappedSuperclass:`)

I tried to replace `@MappedSuperclass` with `@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)` but now I'm getting runtime errors when loading another class that one of their properties is a set of B.

```
org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter.logExceptions(JDBCExceptionReporter.java:78) - Unknown column 'A.createdDateTime' in 'order clause'
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not initialize a collection: [com.acmy.AnotherClassC.classBset#975905b5-d59c-4e53-98dd-30cf39b0c831]
```

What would be a smooth way of fixing class A that uses both `@Entity` and `@MappedSuperclass` to use `@Entity` and `@Inheritance`? Do I need any SQL to fix existing data?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hibernate inheritance, Collections and @OrderedBy superclass attribute generates MySQL syntax Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5393526/hibernate-inheritance-collections-and-orderedby-superclass-attribute-generates)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove the `@MappedSuperClass` Annotation - but leave the `@Entity` and the `@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)`.

You can not use `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)` but i.e. `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)`

**UPDATE**

An example - works for me

Register the generator in a `package-info` Class

**package-info.java**

```
@GenericGenerator(name = "system-uuid", strategy = "uuid")
package db;

import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;
```

Your class A **ClassA.java**

```
package db;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Objects;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Inheritance;
import javax.persistence.InheritanceType;

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public class ClassA implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "system-uuid")
    private String id;

    private String value;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 7;
        hash = 67 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.id);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final ClassA other = (ClassA) obj;
        if (!Objects.equals(this.id, other.id)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "db.ClassA[ id=" + id.toString() + " ]";
    }
}
```

And the inherited Class B **ClassB.java**

```
package db;

import javax.persistence.DiscriminatorValue;
import javax.persistence.Entity;

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("B")
public class ClassB extends ClassA {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "db.ClassB[ id=" + getId() + " ]";
    }
}
```

Last but not least a main class for testing

**TestDb.java**

```
package db;

import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

public class TestDb {
    EntityManager em;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestDb().start();
    }

    public void start() {
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("dbtest");
        em = emf.createEntityManager();
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        ClassA a = new ClassA();
        a.setValue("A");
        em.persist(a);
        a = new ClassA();
        a.setValue("B");
        em.persist(a);
        ClassB b = new ClassB();
        b.setValue("C");
        em.persist(b);
        em.getTransaction().commit();

        em.getTransaction().begin();
        List list = em.createQuery("from " + ClassA.class.getSimpleName() + " c order by c.value").getResultList();
        System.out.println("List " + list);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
    }
}
```

The **persistence.xml** looks like this. I use the h2database with an `im-memory` database

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="dbtest" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <class>db.ClassA</class>
        <class>db.ClassB</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:h2:mem:"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="app"/>
            <!--property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver"/-->
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="app"/>
            <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="create"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: I did replace `@MappedSuperclass` with `@InharitanceThe(strategy=Inh...)`. And root class (parent of class A) is using @GeneratedValue(generator = "system-uuid") and @GenericGenerator(name = "system-uuid", strategy = "uuid")

Comment: No... same error. I cannot change the generator strategy. There is tons of data already in place.

Comment: I have made an example. I have put the generator in the `package-info`

Comment: I think the big problem I'm having is because of existing data. If I use `@Inheritance...` with a fresh clean database, it works fine. My problem is not simply with `@Inheritance` annotation, but moving from `@MappedSuperclass` to `@Inheritance`...

Comment: I have edited my example and add a column `value` to class `ClassA`. In the test I have made an `order by value` - it works. There should not be any problems with an existing database. Your exception looks like a missing field `createdDateTime` in your class `A`.

Comment: I've found the issue. It had nothing to do with existing data. There was another class with get methods referring to both of A and B. Once I removed the `@OrderBy` clause everything is working fine now. I'll update my question soon.

Comment: Just found one more thing... this is a Hibernate bug! It was fixed only in version 4.1.5!!! :(
https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-4394

Comment: I think I'd better mark my question as duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5393526/hibernate-inheritance-collections-and-orderedby-superclass-attribute-generates

Comment: Seems to be the same Problem. Good luck